# How to set certain time period for displaying success message and redirecting to login page in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

I need to display the success message for 2 mins after registration and it should redirect to login page after 2 mins.As i tried with the following code but it is not working.Here is my code.Here is my total updated code.

```
var app = angular.module('accountantApp', []);
app.controller('UserRegistrationController', function($scope, $http, $location,$timeout) {  
$scope.submitRegistrationForm = function(isValid, user) {
    if (isValid) {
        console.log($scope.user);
        $scope.emailError = "";
        $scope.error = "";          
        $http({
          method    : 'POST',
          url       : '../model/signup.php',              
          headers   : {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
          data      : $scope.user

        }).success(function(data, status, headers) {

            console.log("data is::"+JSON.stringify(data));
            if (data.success != undefined && data.success != '')
            {
                $scope.hideForm = "true";
                $scope.success = data.success;
                $scope.user = "";
                console.log("Success message is:"+data.success);
                $timeout(function() {
        $scope.success = false;
        window.location.href = "login.php";
    }, 1000);
                window.location.href = "login.php";
            } else 
            {                   

                if(data.error == "Please Enter Correct Captcha."){
                    $scope.captchaError =  data.error;
                }else if(data.error == "Email-Id already Exists."){
                    $scope.emailError =  data.error;
                }else{
                    $scope.error = data.error;
                }
                console.log("error message is:"+data.error);
            }


        }).error(function(data, status, headers) {
            $scope.user = '';
            alert("Error occured while creating new account:"+status);
                    });         
    } else{
        $scope.submitted = true;
        alert("Please fill the form.");
        return;
    } 
};
$scope.goToLogin = function(){
    console.log("login called");
    window.location.href = "login.php";
}
});
```

Comment: what is happening now?dont you think 2 mins is a bit long for the user to wait to be directed?

Comment: So what's the issue with above logic ?

Comment: may be not inject $timeout to controller

Comment: After registering it is displaying success message and immediately it is redirecting to login page but it should show success message for 2 mins

Comment: try `$.when($timeout(function() {
            $scope.success = false;
        }, 1000000)).then(window.location.href = "login.php");` @Nagu

Comment: @guradio it is not working showing the success message immediately redirecting to login page

Comment: @hadiJZ in the controller i have passed $timeout app.controller('UserRegistrationController', function($scope, $http, $location,$timeout) {

Comment: Can anyone help this problem

Comment: can you post your controller as well?

Comment: @AlexRumba this is my controller app.controller('UserRegistrationController', function($scope, $http, $location,$timeout)

Comment: i can still see your  window.location.href = "login.php"; just before else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$timeout().then` function.

```
   .success(function(data, status, headers) {

        console.log("data is::"+JSON.stringify(data));
        if (data.success != undefined && data.success != '')
        {
            $scope.hideForm = "true";
            $scope.success = data.success;
            $scope.user = "";
            console.log("Success message is:"+data.success);
            $timeout(function() {
                            $scope.success = "going to login page.";
                      }, 10000).then(function(){window.location.href = "login.php";});
            //window.location.href = "login.php"; comment this line.
        } else 
        {                   

            if(data.error == "Please Enter Correct Captcha."){
                $scope.captchaError =  data.error;
            }else if(data.error == "Email-Id already Exists."){
                $scope.emailError =  data.error;
            }else{
                $scope.error = data.error;
            }
            console.log("error message is:"+data.error);
        }


    }).error(function(data, status, headers) {
        $scope.user = '';
        alert("Error occured while creating new account:"+status);
                });         
} else{
    $scope.submitted = true;
    alert("Please fill the form.");
    return;
}
```

Comment: did you remove window.location.href outside of timeout function?

Comment: Ya i have removed that

Comment: can you post your controller as well?

Comment: app.controller('UserRegistrationController', function($scope, $http, $location,$timeout)

Comment: i meant the detailed controller in your question itelf buddy.

Comment: see, my code, and comment the line i have commented.

Comment: I have commented the line and checked it is showing false and redirecting to login page immediately

Comment: lol, i overwrote my own answer thats why, wait. Let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the window.location.href (redirection line outside) the timeout, place it inside. Doing so will only redirect after 1000 seconds.

```
       $timeout(function() {
            $scope.success = false;
            window.location.href = "login.php";
        }, 1000000);
```

Comment: You can reduce the time during testing to 3000 ms. Please let me know what gets printed after 3 secs.

Comment: Iam not getting what you are saying After displaying success message for 3 mins it should redirect to login page

Comment: I am not sure how you setTimeout in angular, but if it js, it would have been like this: `setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="example.com"},5000);`

Answer (score 0):

Change this to

`$timeout(function() {
            $scope.success = false;
        }, 1000000);
        window.location.href = "login.php";`

To

`$timeout(function() {
            $scope.success = false;
            window.location.href = "login.php";
        }, 1000000);`

The redirect should be inside the timeout.

Comment: Did you check the console for any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Remove                             window.location.href = "login.php"; after the $timeout. Its not required.